# ctypes c_char_p_array_64 object in Python

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I am trying to load and call functions from DLL file in python.
A part of my code is below:

```
listdyn= (ctypes.c_char_p * len(list1_))(*list1_)

print type(listdyn)
```

Output: main.c_char_p_Array_64'

I should do a bitwise operation with c_char_p(or string)

I have 2 questions

1) Does listdyn became pointer of pointers by this way?

2) How do I convert into string or c_char_p

Answer (score 0):

2) How do I convert into string or c_char_p
If you have only string values in `list1_` then use the next code to convert `listdyn` to string:

```
print ''.join([ctypes.cast(i, ctypes.c_char_p).value for i in listdyn])
```

or simply (as [eryksun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205580/eryksun) correctly noticed):

```
print ''.join(listdyn[:])
```

but the problem is, that it is possible to have int values in `list1_`. E. g.:

```
list1_ = ['Demo', '', 'string', 0, 'value', 123]
```

String objects' values (`'Demo'`, `''`, `'string'` and `value`) could be found by their (objects') addressess, but int values (0 and 123) will be stored in c_char_p_Array as addresses (0x00 and 0x7b = 123 in hex). Therefore if you'll try to get the value of 5th item (123) using code:

`print ctypes.cast(listdyn[5], ctypes.c_char_p).value`, on Windows the next error will occur:

`ValueError: invalid string pointer 0x000000000000007B`

But under Linux segmentation fault occur.

So, if int values are in `list1_` under Windows try to use this code:

```
result_list = []
listdyn_addr = (ctypes.c_void_p * len(listdyn)).from_buffer(listdyn)
for i in xrange(0, len(listdyn)):
    str_pointer = listdyn_addr[i]
    try:
        value = ctypes.c_char_p(str_pointer).value
        if value == '':
            result_list.append('')
        else:
            result_list.append(0 if not value else value)
    except:
        result_list.append(str_pointer)
print result_list
```

Result:

```
['Demo', '', 'string', 0, 'value', 123]
```

Comment: It's just `listdyn[:]` to get a list of strings. You can't depend on a `ValueError` for a bad string pointer. On POSIX platforms trying to access a bad pointer signals a segfault. Raising exceptions is only present on Windows via the ctypes SEH handler and, in this case, by calling the deprecated and highly discouraged Win32 function [`IsBadStringPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366714%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: `IsBadStringPtr` is obsolete because it can't be trusted in multithreaded code. ctypes shouldn't call it, really. It's only used to permit showing the string in the `c_char_p` repr on Windows, which is inconsistent with other platforms that only show the address (e.g. `c_char_p(12345678)`).

Comment: Again, getting an index or slice of the array creates Python strings, so the casting isn't necessary. Also, to get just the addresses I'd create a `c_void_p` array that shares the same buffer, e.g. `listdyn_addr = (ctypes.c_void_p * len(listdyn)).from_buffer(listdyn)`. Then you can use simple array indexing. There's no need for manual pointer arithmetic or buffer unpacking using the struct module.